# unable to git clone from openshift jenkins static slave

Tags: jenkins, openshift, openshift-cartridge

Some explanations:

- Cartridge A: nginx, jenkins client

  Cartridge B(static slave for jenkins): nginx

  Cartridge C: jenkins

I have setup a cartridge from open shift to be a static slave in jenkins 
now to process is that i push in git something to A and then jenkins starts a build process 
the build process is using B as it's slave

problem is that when the build process tries to clone from A's git repo it fails:

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
Building remotely on nginxbuild (nginx-build) in workspace  /var/lib/openshift/(UUID)/app-root/runtime/repo
Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/(UUID)/app-root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.Channel@afdc78:nginxbuild
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision d50c6e11d2c15015db1ab9665c6dcce758dddd7d (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/(UUID)/app-    root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@910502
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone ssh://(UUID)@nginx-domain.rhcloud.com/~/git/nginx.git
ERROR: Cause: Error performing command: git clone --progress -o origin ssh://(UUID)@nginx-domain.rhcloud.com/~/git/nginx.git     /var/lib/openshift/(UUID)/app-root/runtime/repo
Command "git clone --progress -o origin ssh://(UUID)@nginx-domain.rhcloud.com/~/git/nginx.git     /var/lib/openshift/(UUID)/app-root/runtime/repo" returned     status code 128: Cloning into '/var/lib/openshift/(UUID)/app-    root/runtime/repo'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

so from googling around what i understood is that it had something to do with that the cartridges don't have each others public keys,
 so with ssh i used ssh-keygen and created a public key for A, and for B
and i put them in the manage panel in openShift account control panel 
that didn't resolve the problem.. 
so i tried to add it manualy to the cartridges but.. i don't have any permissions to access the .ssh folder 
 
i also thought that maybe the user Jenkins Admin was causing the problem 
so i even added to his credentials the public keys, but that didn't help..

is there something that I'm missing, 
it's weird for me because when jenkins generates a slave it has no issues, 
it shouldn't be so difficult to create a static slave with openShift..

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried the recommended way in case of authentication issues "Use the interactive setup wizard" as mentioned in [OpenShift's User Guide , 3.2.7. Resolving Authentication Issues?](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-Resolving_Authentication_Issues.html)

Comment: yep tried that, but the problem isn't the authentication between me and the cartridges, it's between cartridge A and B

Comment: I have the same problem here. May I know did you found the solution?

Comment: Did you copy the private key to your slave's file system and set it up in your jenkins (e.g. here `https://jenkins-<yourAccount>.rhcloud.com/credentials/`) as described in [my post](https://itaffinity.wordpress.com/2015/08/09/building-github-projects-on-jenkins-slaves-on-openshift/)?

Comment: Thanks for quick and helpful response, I overload your post at https://itaffinity.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/building-github-projects-with-jenkins-maven-and-sonarqube-4-1-1-on-openshift/, by following the way you setup Jenkins server, especially creating key to git-ssh directory, no problem to pull the code from github and build it. But the Jenkins build occasionally and randomly hitting "Slave went offline during the build". Did you faced similar problem?

Comment: @limcheekin this is most likely due to low memory on your node. Did you follow step 5 of my post (`-Xmx512m`)? If so, you can try to further decrease the value, e.g. `-Xmx256m`